# Locking an object during json.Marshal in Go

Tags: json, go

I wanted to add a RLock/RUnlock to a struct when it was being marshalled into json.
The example below shows what I try to do. However, it doesn't work because every `json.Marshal` is called, it will run the `Object.MarshalJSON` method, which in itself calls json.Marshal, causing an infinite loop.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "sync"
)

type Object struct {
    Name string
    Value int

    sync.RWMutex
}

func (o *Object) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    o.RLock()
    defer o.RUnlock()

    fmt.Println("Marshalling object")

    return json.Marshal(o)
}

func main() {
    o := &Object{Name: "ANisus", Value: 42}

    j, err := json.Marshal(o)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", j)
}
```

[Example in Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/F0uMTL1naX)

Output:

> Marshalling Object
>   Marshalling Object
>   Marshalling Object
>   ...

Obviously, I can delete the MarshalJSON method and call Lock() inside the main function, before calling json.Marshal. But, my question is rather:

Is there any way to call json.Marshal (or at least have the json package handle the encoding) within a struct's MarshalJSON method?

*Bonus question*
Why doesn't my program freeze? Shouldn't the struct be locked when MarshalJSON is called recursively the second time?

Comment: why do you want to lock the object?

Comment: @Akira: If I have multiple goroutines sharing the object, I want to prevent other routines from changing the data while encoding it. In my example I don't have that, but the example was not meant to show actual usage.

Comment: depending on the size of the object to encode: copying the structure is a valid option, imho.

Comment: @Akira: Copying a struct is not an atomic operation. I would still need to Lock it during the copy to prevent a data race. So it would still be the same problem.

Comment: true. still, i consider `time(copy(x)) < time(marshal(x))` and thus the locking might over be faster.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can alias the type on the recursive call.  Here it is on [Play](http://play.golang.org/p/KPXqw3AOwK).

The aliased type (JObject) doesn't have the marshal function defined, so it doesn't infinitely recurse

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "sync"
)

type Object struct {
    Name string
    Value int

    sync.RWMutex
}

//Type alias for the recursive call
type JObject Object

func (o *Object) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    o.RLock()
    defer o.RUnlock()

    fmt.Println("Marshalling object")
    // This works because JObject doesn't have a MarshalJSON function associated with it
    return json.Marshal(JObject(*o)) 
}

func main() {
    o := &Object{Name: "ANisus", Value: 42}

    j, err := json.Marshal(o)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", j)
}
```

Comment: Perfect. The alias solution is doing exactly what I tried to achieve. It works when using the type in nested structs, and it doesn't require any changes to my struct. Thanks!

Comment: This solution copies a mutex, which is unsafe (go vet raises an error).

Comment: Hmm, while `go vet` is correct... generally bad mojo to copy a mutex.  The copied mutex is never used, so it's actually safe.   Maybe this usage patterns isn't something vet can't comprehend.  I suppose one could make 2 types Object and `type LockableObject struct { Object, sync.RWMutex }` .  and marshal only marshals the Object part, but Lock works on whole lockable guy

Answer (score 2):

**Simple Answer :**
Your program freezes because of Infinite recursion.

You called  `json.Marshal(o)` which would look `MarshalJSON()` in your methods but unfortunately you also called `json.Marshal(o)` in `MarshalJSON()` which ultimately leads to infinite cause recursion and using up the systems memory

Its called [common rookie mistake](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=5173) because your code would lead to infinite recursion.

Here is a simpler version of your code using `String()`

**Another recursion Example:**

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A int

func (a A) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v", a)
}

func main() {
    var a A
    fmt.Println("this will never print", a)
}
```

That is why go is trying to  [impose stack size limit](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/detail?r=aeb72c90c10ec8e93ef964067bd30f52d030e635) as a temporal solution

2 Simple Solutions

- Use another name
- Don't return `return json.Marshal(o)` but Item

**Solution 1 Example**

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Object struct {
    Name  string
    Value int

    sync.RWMutex
}

func (o *Object) ParseJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    o.RLock()
    defer o.RUnlock()

    fmt.Println("Marshalling object")

    return json.Marshal(o)
}

func main() {
    o := &Object{Name: "ANisus", Value: 42}

    j, err := o.ParseJSON() // THis would work
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", j)

    j, err = json.Marshal(o) // this would work
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", j)
}
```

[Live Demo](http://play.golang.org/p/LAP4Dixb7F)

**Solution 2 Example**

package main

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Item struct {
    Name  string
    Value int

}
type Object struct {
    item Item
    sync.RWMutex
}

func (o *Object) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    o.RLock()
    defer o.RUnlock()

    fmt.Println("Marshalling object")
    return json.Marshal(o.item)
}

func main() {
    o := &Object{item : Item{Name: "ANisus", Value: 42}}

    j, err := json.Marshal(o)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", j)
}
```

[Live Demo](http://play.golang.org/p/QQZQJxzz9Q)

Comment: I went with David Budworth solution because it was most close to the solution I was asking for. But +1 for nice workarounds to avoid the recursion problem.